# Cross compilation error with QtCreator [Yocto Image]

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I've bitbaked a qt5 image for my Beaglebone Black and exported the cross-toolchain sdk.
I also tried to setup QtCreator to work with the output toolchain with the steps in this [link](http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=HIO_Wiki:Set_Up_Qt_Creator_for_Yocto_Device)

I put this code at the beginning of the qtcreator.sh file to change the environment variables

> source /opt/poky/1.6.1/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

and configured the following options

- **qmake**:
  /home/user/cross/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake
- **g++ compiler**:
  /home/user/cross/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
- **Sysroot**: /home/user/cross/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi

However, when I build the project I get the following errors :

`error: cannot find -lQt5Widgets 
error: cannot find -lQt5Core 
error: cannot find -lQt5Gui 
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Does anybody have a solution for this?

*P.S.* when I compile the project using terminal it compiles with no error and works well on the target. My host machine is running on Ubuntu 16.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this in case somebody has the same issue.

the solution is to add `linux-oe-g++` in the "Qt mkspec" of the kit you created in the QtCreator.