# Cross compilation error with QtCreator [Yocto Image] in Ubuntu 14

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cross-compiling

Qt Creator is giving this library error:

```
11:13:12: Running steps for project qtConsoleTest...
11:13:12: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" clean
rm -f main.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
11:13:12: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
11:13:12: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:13:12: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../qtConsoleTest -I. -isystem /opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -isystem /opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../qtConsoleTest/main.cpp
g++  -o qtConsoleTest main.o   -lQt5Core -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Core
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qtConsoleTest] Error 1
11:13:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qtConsoleTest (kit: ce3TunnelBoard)
When executing step "Make"
11:13:13: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Based on this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960709/cross-compilation-error-with-qtcreator-yocto-image), I think my problem is that QMAKE_SPEC and QMAKE_XSPEC under Qt Versions should be showing linux-oe-g++ (instead of linux-g++) but I don't know how to change that. Have I missed any steps?

I've bitbaked Qt5 SDK, I've also sourced the environment in "/opt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator.sh" by adding this at the top:

```
source /opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/environment-setup-cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

and configured the following options under Debuggers, Compilers & Qt Versions respectively:

```
/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gdb
/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
/opt/fsl-imx-x11/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake
```

These are the screenshots just in case.

[image: I'd appreciate] any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last screen shot shows a text entry labeled *Qt mkspec*. This is where you should enter `linux-oe-g++` to override the default value of `linux-g++` for your `c3TunnelBoard` kit. See [this link](https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-yocto-development) for more information on how to set up QtCreator for use with a Yocto toolchain.